# change title of a page with angularjs routing

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the page title of my page using routing, so far my title s getting changed but my url is being appended in the title. Any clue as to why?

index.html:

```
<title ng-bind-html="title ">Website Name</title>
```

JS file

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
         .state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "partials/content/dashboard.html",
            controller: "dashboardCtrl"
         })
 });

app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {   
         //set it here
     $rootScope.title = $state.current.title;        
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$routeChangeSuccess` .

```
app.run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });
    }]);
```

Then in **Html** , Use `ng-bind`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title ng-bind="'myApp &mdash; ' + title">myApp</title>
```

Fore more reference read - [How to dynamically change header based on AngularJS partial view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view) or [How to set page title with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326307/how-to-set-page-title-with-angular)

Comment: can you elaborate more , how you implemented?

Comment: I simply used this in my controller
$rootScope.title = 'my title';
and the same HTML as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Just put it into **data**:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {  
   .state('dashboard', { 
         url: "/dashboard", 
         templateUrl:      "partials/content/dashboard.html",  
         controller: "dashboardCtrl",
         data: {
             title: 'Dashboard title'
          }
 }) });
```

Comment: $rootScope.title = $state.current.data.title;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `title` property for the `when` function of [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider), like so:

```
var module = angular.module('yourApp.routes', []);

module.config([
    '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
             .when('/dashboard', {
                 title: 'Dashboard',
                 templateUrl: "partials/content/dashboard.html",
                 controller: "dashboardCtrl"
              })
    }
]);

return module;
```

Title can be accessed in `$scope` or in a view:

```
<h1 data-ng-bind="::title"></h1>
```